# How to invoke a function with type?

Tags: c#

So I have this custom object / static function that take a Type to call:

```
      MyObject<MyType>.MyFunction();
```

MyObject is defined as such:

```
      public abstract class MyObject <type> { ... }
```

How do I invoke it?  The reason I need to do invoking is because MyType is dynamic, and I can't do this:

```
     Type t = this.GetType();
     MyObject<t>.MyFunction();
```

Comment: are you aware of the keyword typeof ?  This should work just fine: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/twcad0zb(v=vs.80).aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'd need to use reflection to instantiate the class - and then more reflection to invoke the method:

```
Type typeDefinition = typeof(MyObject<>);
Type constructedType = typeDefinition.MakeGenericType(t);
MethodInfo method = constructedType.GetMethod("MyFunction");
method.Invoke(null, null);
```

It's unpleasant, certainly. Do you definitely *need* it to be a method in a generic class?

Comment: Using reflection to get a generic method feels nasty to me... is there any reason OP can't just use standard generic boilerplate?

Comment: @YongkeBillYu: Yup, that's what you get for mixing generics (designed for *compile-time* type checking) with supplying the types at *execution* time.

Comment: @JTorres I (wrongfully) thought I remmebered that GetMethod would only return public instance method. It returns both static and instance methods. The invoke has nothing to do with whether or not the method is static (yes you need to pass null if static and instance if not but that does not affect whether or not it is static)

Answer (score 1):

```
typeof(MyObject<>).MakeGenericType(this.GetType())
    .GetMethod("MyFunction", BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public)
    .Invoke(null, null);
```

Answer (score 1):

Only by using reflection.

```
typeof(MyObject<>).MakeGenericType(t).GetMethod("MyFunction", BindingFlags.Static).Invoke(null, new object[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you aware of the keyword typeof ?

This should work just fine: [msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/twcad0zb(v=vs.80).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/twcad0zb%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)